# Problem With Inserts of multibyte (converted to utf-8) strings in the mysql tables of utf_unicode_ci encoding

Tags: php, mysql, utf

http://domainsoutlook.com/sandbox/keyword/?s=http://bhaskar.com

raw example of my keyword density analyser. Every keyword shows up properly with no problems in unicode conversions etc.

Now, When I am adding these words to the database column of a table, the words show up as messed up.

http domainsoutlook.com/b/site/bhaskar.com.html

For example on this front end page if you see there is a keyword that is shown as a blank but still occurs on the website 8 times. (It isnt empty in the database though).

I have checked and there is no problem with mysql_real_escape_String...because the output stays the same before and after the word is gone through mysql_real_escape_String.

Another problem was that I wanted to fix my urls for arabic language. They should be showing up as /word-{1st letter of the word}/{whole word}.html but its showing as /word-{whole word}/{1st letter of the word}.html

I really need answers for these two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reinserting and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting utf-8 character set for mysql connection in your php script

```
mysql_connect(...)
mysql_select_db(...);
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

Comment: can you post code that handles inserting data into db and displaying data from it?